# Which credentials are used to refresh dataset pointing to a web data source (excel file in SharePoint)?

Tags: powerbi

When I use a web data source (excel file located in SharePoint) and publish the PBI report, then in PBI portal I need to configure the dataset connection by using Organisational account (type:Oauth2).

Does this mean that my account credentials will always be used by the gateway to refresh that dataset or will credentials of the person who clicks the dataset refresh button be used?